# Missing Git Repository dependency for package in BuildRoot

Tags: git, embedded-linux, buildroot, qwt

I'm currently working on a project that utilizes compiling an embedded Linux image using BuildRoot for a BeagleBone Black OBC, and am pulling my hair out for an issue I don't know how to approach to solve.

The Linux project I am trying to build is called [KubOS](https://github.com/kubos/kubos-linux-build), and like I mentioned is using BuildRoot v2019.2.2. I've followed the required steps for generating the makeconfig file for my particular board, and for the first half of the build process everything seems to be fine.

Unfortunately, when trying to build some of the packages that are included in the final build, I reach a point where BuildRoot is trying to find a dependency that no longer exists.

```
$ sudo make
>>> pothos-core pothos-0.7.1 Downloading
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/garrett/Documents/quest_kubos_compile/buildroot-2019.02.2/dl/pothos-core/git/.git/
Fetching all references
Could not fetch special ref 'pothos-0.7.1'; assuming it is not special.
Deregistering submodule "audio"
Deregistering submodule "blocks"
Deregistering submodule "comms"
Deregistering submodule "flow"
Deregistering submodule "muparserx"
Deregistering submodule "plotters"
Deregistering submodule "poco"
Deregistering submodule "python"
Deregistering submodule "soapy"
Deregistering submodule "spuce"
Deregistering submodule "widgets"
Submodule path 'audio': checked out 'ab7c7da97a00222c1c95818f3d453fa8d877314e'
Submodule path 'blocks': checked out '3f89875f9e2f40cc24a740595c62deadb7e1c27b'
Submodule path 'comms': checked out '47c363b0bf3ad931aa815251200c2481d013b725'
Submodule path 'flow': checked out 'ebb4870a1af4fed5f5cbceb4b16e5ada7cfe17c7'
Submodule path 'muparserx': checked out '08cbfc3e9087e8fceafc85c8fdb7e034e1c35943'
Submodule path 'plotters': checked out '9388ab943ea9fbe038a00e50bce4bbad8da88e40'
Cloning into '/home/garrett/Documents/kubos_compile/buildroot-2019.02.2/dl/pothos-core/git/plotters/qwt6'...
Username for 'https://github.com': Gman0064
Password for 'https://Gman0064@github.com': 
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/osakared/qwt.git/'
fatal: clone of 'https://github.com/osakared/qwt.git' into submodule path '/home/garrett/Documents/kubos_compile/buildroot-2019.02.2/dl/pothos-core/git/plotters/qwt6' failed
Failed to clone 'qwt6'. Retry scheduled
Cloning into '/home/garrett/Documents/kubos_compile/buildroot-2019.02.2/dl/pothos-core/git/plotters/qwt6'...
Username for 'https://github.com':
```

Initially, it asks for my GitHub credentials, which I have confirmed are correct, and once entered it fails to clone the repository due to missing a "personal access token". I understand that this means it needs an ssh key registered to my GitHub account, so I've generated an SSH key for my user and registered it, and can confirm I am able to clone repositories using that account. However, repeating the process to clone it still fails, and through following the git repository link that it's trying to pull (https://github.com/osakared/qwt.git/), it appears that it has been removed at some point by the author. and cannot be found.

***My question***: How can I remove the package from BuildRoot so that it does not compile it in the final image, or how can I point BuildRoot to another git repository it can use instead?

I'm at odds with how to start solving this issue, as I do not have enough experience with BuildRoot and compiling Linux images from scratch to figure out where to start looking. I have searched through both the KubOS project and BuildRoot files to find where this package is defined and if I can change its reference to some other repository or even remove it, but have been unsuccessful.

I'd be happy to add any more details in future edits if they are needed.

Comment: This is really three questions in one: (a) where did that repository *go?* (I don't know the answer to that one). (b) What's up with Personal Access Tokens on GitHub? (this one is a duplicate). (c) How do I use ssh instead of https on GitHub? (Easy: use ssh *URLs*. Less easy when there are submodules, as the submodules listed in `.gitmodules` list *their own* URLs.) If you'll separate these questions out, they'll be answerable (or already answered).

Comment: None of those questions are what I am asking, I am asking how to remove a package from BuildRoot that is marked to be included in the final image, but is failing to build because the git repo for that package is missing. I am trying to remove the package or point it towards another repository.

Comment: Ah, OK. The added paragraph definitely helps then :-) though you're now down to [tag:buildroot] for relevant tags, I think. Not having used buildroot myself, I don't know the answer.